# Create multile boxplots from nested list in one plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a nested list like this:

```
nested_list = [[1,2,3], [8,9,1,3], [4,5,6,1]]
```

Now I want to make a boxplot for each list in the list, but the boxplots should be in the same graphic. If possible, without a dataframe because of the nans.

Comment: @BigBen I agree. It maybe a homework question. I am of the opinion that even if it is atleast mention that in comment as the questioner to improve. If after comments they don't improve, then downvote. If we do blanket downvote then it will be unwelcoming to new users. If that is what is the goal of stackoverflow then we should be downvoting without giving an explanation to the person who asked the question. Just my thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`plt.boxplot` can take a list of vectors and positions, so its a one-liner:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
nested_list = [[1,2,3], [8,9,1,3], [4,5,6,1]]

plt.boxplot(nested_list, positions=range(len(nested_list)))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nested_list = [[1,2,3], [8,9,1,3], [4,5,6,1]]

fig,ax = plt.subplots()

for i,lst in enumerate(nested_list): 
    ax.boxplot(lst,positions=[i]) 

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]